# How to enable my keyboard's volume keys in XFCE?

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

My keyboard has dedicated keys to change the audio volume and to mute/unmute audio. How can I make these work in XFCE?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

1. Right click a panel -> Panel submenu -> Add New Items...
2. Add an instance of PulseAudio Plugin
3. Right click the icon that just appeared in your panel and click "Properties". Make sure "Enable keyboard shortcuts for volume control" is enabled.

You may have to install the PulseAudio Plugin first. In Debian and Debian-based distributions, the package is called `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`.

Comment: For future searchers: this solved my problem in a Thinkpad X1 when upgrading from Debian jessie to Debian stretch

Comment: nice. Worked for my setup: Ubuntu 18 + xfce4

Comment: I dont want an item in my panel just for working hotkeys. Pretty strange solution

Comment: @Blauhirn You can instead install `xfce4-volumed-pulse` (which appears to be packaged as `xfce4-volumed` in Ubuntu 18.04) to get hotkey support without a panel plugin. [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/xfce4-volumed-pulse)

Comment: This fixed the problem for me in Fedora 30.

Comment: If you don't have Multimedia keys here's a suggestion for keybindings: Volume Up `ALT` + `PageUp`, Volume Down `ALT` + `PageDown`, Mute `ALT` + `Pos1`.

Though it is more of a Windows standard to use the PageUp and Down keys for volume it is mapped in a lot of software, too. Still, Firefox uses `STRG` + `Page Up` to switch between Tabs so just use `ALT`.

Comment: Installing xfce4-volumed was what really fixed my problem, as @Jon suggested.

Comment: Worked great on Mint 19 with a laptop that doesn't have media keys.  I set it to Alt + Up and Alt + Down.  This solution even shows the volume up and down indicator when pressed.  Perfect!

Answer (score 36):

1.-Configuration

2.-Keyboard

3.-Application shortcuts

4.-Add

```
amixer -D pulse set Master 5%+     --> (Volume Up)
amixer -D pulse set Master 5%-     --> (Volume Down)
amixer -D pulse set Master toggle  --> (Mute/Unmute)
```

**Update:**

The parameter `-D pulse` was added to the command so it would work with current versions of xfce4 using pulseaudio for sound.

[image]

Comment: Adding the mute/unmute toggle only mutes the audio. When I press the same key combo, the audio is not unmuted. On Ubuntu 18.04 + xfce4. The volume up and down commands works well.

Comment: I've used Enable keyboard shortcuts for volume control = Off, combined with amixer set Master 20%- command on Mute hotkey, to disable Mute hotkey and instead of Mute do a rapid volume reduce. Its more convenient than Mute :)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 / xfce4 I had to use `amixer -D pulse set Master 15%-`  without the "-D pulse" the volume did not change.

Comment: Use "amixer -D pulse set Master 1+ toggle" to make also unmute working

Comment: Thanks. Also used this to toggle the microphone: `amixer -D pulse set Capture toggle --> (Mic Mute/Unmute)`

Answer (score 22):

Please notice, that both answers are correct, but each depend on different packages for the sound management. Erik here uses     `pulseaudio`
while Samuel Loza's answer implies, that     `alsamixer`
is used.

## `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin`

1. Right click a panel -> Panel submenu -> Add New Items...
2. Add an instance of PulseAudio Plugin
3. Right click the icon that just appeared in your panel and click "Properties". Make sure "Enable keyboard shortcuts for volume control" is enabled. -> See: Sound settings -> Audio mixer will tell you what package you use. If `pulseadio` is used the field should tell `pavucontrol`.
4. Open the configuration for your keyboard shortcuts and add the following commands: 
    `pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +10%` # raise volume by each 10% (more than 100% possible, might distort the sound) 
   `pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -10%`   # reduce volume by each 10% 
   `pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle`   # mute/unmutes audio

## `alsamixer` (compare Samuel's answer)

1. Check if alsamixer is working as your sound management.
2. Go see the configuration for keyboard shortcuts and edit: 
   `amixer set Master 10%+ #` raise volume by each 10 % 
   `amixer set Master 10%- #` reduce volume by each 10 % 
   `amixer set Master toggle #` mute/unmute audio

The first solution works for me on Debian stretch, I had problems with the sound after the upgrade from jessie. The settings work while using headphones as well. One can adapt the amount of increase/decrease in % freely.

Duplicated questions: 
[How to increase or decrease volume in Xfce with keyboard shortcuts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355665/how-to-increase-or-decrease-volume-in-xfce-with-keyboard-shortcuts?rq=1) (English, NA) 
[Muting and unmuting sound with mutebutton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124651/muting-and-unmuting-sound-with-mutebutton) (English, Debian jessie)

Further links: 
https://wiki.debian.org/Sound (English, Debian) 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/xfce4-volumed/+bug/883485 (English, Debian+Ubuntu)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/652890/shortcuts-volume-specific-output (English, Ubuntu 15.04) 
[Lower or increase pulseaudio volume on all outputs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374085/lower-or-increase-pulseaudio-volume-on-all-outputs) (English, Debian sid) 
https://mysudo.wordpress.com/2015/03/27/unmute-pulseaudio-sound-in-xfce-debian-jessie/ (German, Debian jessie) 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342661 (English, Ubuntu)

Comment: Alsamixer should always work, even when using Pulseaudio

Comment: pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +10% with @DEFAULT_SINK@ instead of 0 as mentioned in the answer below helped me. I just add this as a comment so that other people find the remark immediately.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to use `pactl -- set-sink-volume 0 +10%` did not work for me.

Using `@DEFAULT_SINK@` instead of `0` as the sink worked for me.

Example:

`pactl -- set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +10%`

Comment: Should this be a comment on [Sebastian's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412926/117549)?

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the files in ~/.config/pulse then running the following in the terminal should fix it:

`pulseaudio -k`

You may need to restart your sound playing apps after that, and if pulseaudio doesn't restart on its own, this will restart it:

`pulseaudio --start`

Okay. At the **bottom of the window** `click` on **Add**. In the window that open for the command enter this:

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 3%+ unmute`

Now click on Ok, then it'll ask you to press the key(s) you want to assign to that command. Just press your volume up button and it should be done.

You can then repeat the process using this for the volume decrease button:

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 3%- unmute`

If you have a mute button as well, repeat one more time using this:

`amixer -D pulse sset Master toggle`

In case your permissions got messed up, this terminal command will fix them (I don't know any other way to do this, sorry!):

`sudo chown -Rc $USER:$USER $HOME`