# Amixer returning wrong audio value

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, audio, volume

Running the command:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 30%
```

should set the audio volume to 30% right?

When running:

```
amixer get Master
```

It returns saying the audio volume is 52%.

Any explanation or solution to my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32206/set-volume-from-terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulseaudio has its own set of volume controls, and the `pulse` device is the converter that lets ALSA-only applications use Pulseaudio.

I very much doubt setting *any* mixer control on the `pulse` device does anything sensible. And I'm not sure which value reading mixer controls would return, possible the volume setting of the default sink (but I'd have to read the source code to find out).

If you want to control the volume of Pulseaudio applications from the commandline (no matter if they use Pulseaudio via ALSA, or directly), have a look at `pacmd`.

Comment: Hmmm intersting... However I've no idea on how to use pacmd to change the volume and get the volume. Can you please explain how to use it? Thanks

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374085/lower-or-increase-pulseaudio-volume-on-all-outputs), or one of the other similar questions.